# Facebook Open Graph Api Auth error even though post is successful

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, api, graph

I'm creating an application to manage posting on Facebook. 
I can post a basic Facebook message with no error and upload a local image in my page album.

The problem lies in the later. After uploading my image and using it's ID to capture the source for my image post, the message is succesfully posted but gives an authentication error.

I'm using Ajax to do this and notice that (looking at my code), my console prints the following order:
1. "succes 01"
2. "complete"
3. "succes 02"
instead of
1. "succes 01"
2. "succes 02"
3. "complete"

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + response.access_token,
type: 'POST',
data: data,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
cache: false,
success:function (data) {

    FB.api( // BEGIN: IMAGE HAS BEEN UPLOADED, NOW LET'S GET THE IMAGE URL TO USE
      '/'+ data.id,
      'GET',
      {"fields":"images"},
      function(response) {
        var getFirstImage = response.images[0].source;
        console.log("succes 02");   

        FB.api( // BEGIN OF FB API TO POST BASIC MESSAGE
          '/'+ val + '/feed',
          'POST',
          {message: message, link: link, source: getFirstImage, access_token: response.access_token},
          function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $("#" + val).addClass('postsucces');
            $(".feedbackresponse").html("<span class='succesFeedback'>Alright! Every post was a succes</span>");
        }); // END OF FB API TO POST BASIC MESSAGE  


    }); // END: IMAGE HAS BEEN UPLOADED, NOW LET'S GET THE IMAGE URL TO USE

    $('.feedbackresponse').append('<p>Photo was successfully uploaded, object id is: ' + data.id + '</p>');
    console.log("succes 01");
},
error:function (data) {
    $('.feedbackresponse').append('<p>A problem occurred during upload</p>');
},
complete: function () {
    console.log("complete");

}
});
```

};

Comment: `FB.api` is asynchronous itself, so of course “completion” of your outer AJAX call does not “wait” for those API calls to finish.

Comment: _“but gives an authentication error”_ - when, where, what error?

Comment: the "console.log(response)" gives the authentication error. But the message has still been posted succesfully.

Error: "(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission"

PS: I do have permissions

Comment: In the inner API call, `response.access_token` should not even be set - `response` _at this point_ is the variable passed to the callback function of your first API call, and since that API call only requests details about a specific image, it should not contain any `access_token` property to begin with. So effectively you most likely have passed `undefined` as the access token in your parameters with the inner API call …

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! That was indeed the problem. I removed the response.access_token